# How to show ADF - Business component SQL query in console?

Tags: oracle-adf

I am trying to show (print in console) the SQL queries corresponding to the ADF-BC's one. I don't know how to do this with Jdeveloper 11.1.1.1.0 and Oracle 11g. I just want to see what SQL queries are going to be executed before sending them to Oracle. The problem is I am working on an existing web application (written in ADF-BC) and the response time is too high. So I'd like to test the query with SQL Developer and make some 'Explain plan' to see how I can optimize it.

Or, if someone knows how to get a SQL query string (in debug mode) from the `executeQueryForCollection(Object qc, Object[] params, int noUserParams)`
method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the app with the Java runtime option 
-Djbo.debugoutput=console
This will print the info in the log window. It with I'll print very much information so you should turn it off quickly. 
To get the same info in a file use 
-Djbo.debugoutput=file
This will print the info into a file and only the file name is written to the log.

Answer (score 3):

With Oracle **12c** and JDeveloper 12.1.3, you have two options:

- If you use integrated weblogic server, you can configure Oracle Diagnostic Logging (Clic on Actions menu in server log window), and put `oracle.jbo` to level `FINEST`
- You can retrieve your SQL query in subclass implementing `oracle.jbo.server.ViewObjectImpl`, in `executeQueryForCollection(Object qc, Object[] params, int noUserParams)` by logging or watching value of `this.getQuery()`

Answer (score 1):

> **Enabling diagnostic messages in standalone WLS** Tested in 12.2.1.2

In the following example will be using the WLS that is shipped with JDeveloper as a standalone in a Windows machine.
Go to WLS bin directory. In our case  %JDEV_SYSTEM_DIR%\DefaultDomain\bin\ 
eg
C:\JDeveloper\mywork\system11.1.1.3.37.56.60\DefaultDomain\bin\ 
(Note: Check related post to find out the JDEV_SYSTEM_DIR from log of the running WLS.)

Open file setDomainEnv.cmd On the top of the file after the comments enter the following line

```
set DIAGNOSTIC_OPTIONS=-Djbo.debugoutput=file -Djbo.logging.show.function=true
```

Then modify the following line

```
set JAVA_PROPERTIES=-Dwls.home=%WLS_HOME% -Dweblogic.home=%WLS_HOME%
```

(in the same line.)
to

```
set JAVA_PROPERTIES=-Dwls.home=%WLS_HOME% -Dweblogic.home=%WLS_HOME% %DIAGNOSTIC_OPTIONS%
```

http://adfhowto.blogspot.ca/2011/01/enable-diagnostic-messages-on-you.html